# Separate Columns for Distinct Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
[profile_id]
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[SurveyResponse] sr0 WHERE sr.profile_id = profile_id AND sr0.[value] = '0' AND sr0.[created_At] > DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE()) )/COUNT(*) as [0 Responses]
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[SurveyResponse] sr25 WHERE sr.profile_id = profile_id AND sr25.[value] = '25'AND sr25.[created_At] > DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE()))/COUNT(*) as [25 Responses]
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[SurveyResponse] sr50 WHERE sr.profile_id = profile_id AND sr50.[value] = '50' AND sr50.[created_At] > DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE()))/COUNT(*) as [50 Responses]
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[SurveyResponse] sr75 WHERE sr.profile_id = profile_id AND sr75.[value] = '75' AND sr75.[created_At] > DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE()))/COUNT(*) as [75 Responses]
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[SurveyResponse] sr100 WHERE sr.profile_id = profile_id AND sr100.[value] = '100' AND sr100.[created_At] > DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE()))/COUNT(*) as [100 Responses]
,COUNT(*) as [Total Responses]
FROM [dbo].[SurveyResponse] sr
  WHERE [created_At] > DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE())
  GROUP BY [profile_id]
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

I have data coming from a survey that users can fill out multiple times a day. 
It allows the user to select 1 of 5 options (0,25,50,75,100). It has columns for profile ID, created at, and value

I am attempting to get the % of times that user picked each option. I also only want to return profiles that have 10 or more responses. So say profile 1 selected 0 5 times, 25 2 times, 50 1 time, 75 2 times, 100 0 times I want it to return

```
Profile ID |  0   |  25  |  50  |  75  |  100
------------------------------------------------
 12345     |  50% |  20% |  10% | 20%  | 0%
```

I have it spitting out the counts of each response in comparison to the total response but there has got to be a better way to implement this than I have above, as well as a way to get it to display %s.

This is in SQL Server

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Aside: `sr50.[value] = '50'` compares a column value to a string. Is the column really a string datatype or do you want the database to apply the rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) to convert to something like an `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things more complicated than they are. You don't need subqueries.

```
select 
  profile_id,
  count(case when value =   0 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*) as [0 Responses],
  count(case when value =  25 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*) as [25 Responses],
  count(case when value =  50 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*) as [50 Responses],
  count(case when value =  75 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*) as [75 Responses],
  count(case when value = 100 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*) as [100 Responses],
  count(*) as [total responses]
from dbo.surveyresponse
where created_at > dateadd(month, -3, getdate())
group by profile_id
having count(*) > 10
order by profile_id;
```

You may want to apply `ROUND`to get less decimals, though :-)

As of SQL Server 2012 you can use `FORMAT` to output a formatted number string.

Comment: I was about to make this a little harder than it needed to be as well.  Glad you answered so quickly.  I would just like to add that the COUNT function works with your case statement because it doesn't count NULLs just in case someone didn't know that.

Comment: @SteveB: Thanks for explaining this. Yes, `count(case when value = 0 then 1 end)` is short for `count(case when value = 0 then 1 else null end)` and nulls are not counted. An alternative often used is `sum(case when value = 0 then 1 else 0 end)`.

Answer (score 1):

I like to simplify this calculation using `avg()`:

```
select profile_id,
       avg(case when value = 0 then 100.0 else 0 end) as [0 Responses],
       avg(case when value = 25 then 100.0 else 0 end) [25 Responses],
       avg(case when value = 50 then 100.0 else 0 end) as [50 Responses],
       avg(case when value = 75 then 100.0 else 0 end) as [75 Responses],
       avg(case when value = 100 then 100.0 else 0 end) as [100 Responses],
       count(*) as [total responses]
from dbo.surveyresponse
where created_at > dateadd(month, -3, getdate())
group by profile_id
having count(*) > 10
order by profile_id;
```